# How to set high score and only changes if it is surpassed

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

Like the game helicopter or like Left 4 dead survival mode I want the score to stay and only change if score is surpassed. Here is the code I have so far.
 ./m file

```
                    _score = 0;
                         _oldScore = -1;
     self.scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 50) alignment:UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
     _scoreLabel.position = ccp(winSize.width - _scoreLabel.contentSize.width, _scoreLabel.contentSize.height);
     _scoreLabel.color = ccc3(255,0,0);
     [self addChild:_scoreLabel z:1];     



if (_score != _oldScore) {
    _oldScore = _score;
    [_scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score%d", _score]];



}
```

and the .h file

```
       int _score;
int _oldScore;
CCLabelTTF *_scoreLabel;
```

I tried to put

```
      _score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_oldScore forKey:@"score"];
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

but when i did that it only saved the data and keeps going up rather than starting over and only change when score is surpassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare if your score is more than the old score and just save it then.

For example,

```
if (_score > _oldscore) {
  // Save out new score as it is more than the old score

  // Then reset ready for next time
  _oldscore = _score;
  _score = 0;
}
```

However, if you are struggling with something like this, I would suggest you are going to be in for a whole lot of problems unless you stop and learn the basics of programming now before progressing further in your development.

Comment: Would be good if you showed what you had tried then - that way we won't waste our time trying to help you by telling you stuff you had already tried. You are obviously not resetting _score and nor are you setting _oldscore to be the previous _score